# Ruby on Rails, reference custom parameter inside form to specific url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input, reference

I need to do a specific form with a parameter that is not associated to the Model that im using. See, i have in my controller (and i can reference them in my view) a specific "Order" and an array of "Products".

```
#this controller responds to mydomain.com/new/order/:id_order
class MyController < ApplicationController
...
  def my_page
    @order = Order.find(params[:id_order])
    @products = Product.all
  end
...
end
```

In my view i need to render a list with all the products with their attributes (name, description, price), a small number field next to each product and a link to "Add" the product.

I can do the table to show every attribute in each individual product of my products array, problem is, i dont know how to create a number field next to each row in my table and a link to the "Add" action, which is just a point in my API, **mydomain.com/add/product/:id_order/:id_product/:amount** (alias as **add_product_order**)

**:id_order** correspond to the id of the order, which i have (@order.id)
**:id_product** correspond to the id of the specific product of the row, which i have (product.id)
**:amount** must be the amount specified by the user, but i have no idea how to reference it inside the view.

The rails helper form_for, form_tag etc ... requires the url to send the data however i cant use **add_product_order_path** because i would need the :amount parameter so it gives me an error (but if i use a constant amount like 1, it works).

In conclusion:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= product.name %></td>
          <td><%= product.description %></td>
          <td><%= product.price %></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="amount" min="1"></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Add', add_product_order_path(id_order: @order.id, id_product: product.id, amount: *???* ), method: :post %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

What would need to be in the **???** to send the value of the amount field to the add_product_order_path?

Comment: Are you trying to make the amount have number picker in the HTML?

Comment: @maxple yes, and reference the value to pass it to the API point

Answer (score 0):

So, the amount value its an input with an unknown value. I highly recommend that use some JS to achieve this. Something like:

```
$('table td a').on('click', function(e) {
   var amountVal = $(this).parent('tr').find('input').val();
   var newUrl = location.href.replace("amount=", "amount="+amountVal);
   $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
});
```

I hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, did'nt saw that you're using `method: :post`, this generates a hidden form, you have to change the hidden input value. Its posible with javascript too:

```
$('table td a').on('click', function(e) {
   var amountVal = $(this).parent('tr').find('input').val();
   $(this).parent().find('input[name*="amount"]').val(amountVal);
});
```

Comment: I dont have a form because forms dont work if i dont have a reference in view of the value, because the action path needs all of the arguments